# angularjs and brackets live preview: The simplest code doesn't work

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm a newbie to angularJS and I'm trying to make the simple thing to work but I fail.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>
    <div class="test" ng-controller="testSrc">
      <p> {{ blah }} </p>
      <img ng-src="{{ URLImage }}"/>
      <button class="btn btn-sucess" ng-click="goYahoo()">Yahoo</button>
      <button class="btn btn-sucess" ng-click="goGoogle()">Google</button>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('testSrc', ['$scope,$location', function ($scope, $location) {
  "use strict";
  $scope.blah = "blah blah";
  $scope.URLImage = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png';

  $scope.goGoogle = function () { $location.url('localhost:58164/g'); };
  $scope.goYahoo = function () { $location.url('localhost:58164/y'); };
}]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  "use strict";
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'index.html'
  })
  .when('/g', {
    templateUrl : 'http://www.google.com'
  })
  .when('/y', {
    templateUrl : 'http://www.yahoo.com'
  });
});
```

The code has passed all lint warnings. I use the live preview of brackets that opens up Internet explorer. I encounter 3 issues:

1) {{ blah }} does not translate into blah blah, I see {{ blah }} as if the js is ignored. same for the ng-src of the img. It is ignored and I don't see the image.

2) the 2 buttons are not colored in green as I expect it to be from the bootstrap css. I tried it in jsFiddle and did see them as green but when I tried again now, they were regular, not sure what did I do wrong.

3) Routing: I want to browse to Google/Yahoo when navigating to specific url g and y using the 2 buttons. When I open the live preview, the url is: http://127.0.0.1:58164/index.html so how can I route this correctly? http://127.0.0.1:58164/index.html/g won't work.

I'm kinda lost here, not sure if the problem is my code, the browser of the live preview though the JS didn't work also in jsFiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You're injecting the dependencies into your controller incorrectly - you need a string for each argument of the function. It's an easy mistake to make!

```
app.controller('testSrc', ['$scope,$location', function ($scope, $location) { // Wrong
app.controller('testSrc', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) { // Right
```

2) You've misspelled the class name in your buttons. 'sucess' should be 'success'.

```
 <button class="btn btn-sucess" ng-click="goYahoo()">Yahoo</button>
                        ^^^^^^
```

3) There's numerous things wrong with your routing:

- You haven't included the ngRoute module in your HTML - it hasn't been included in the base Angular package for a long time now.
- Once that's done, you need to add it as a dependency: `var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);` and add an `ng-view` tag to your HTML.
- By default, the router will use 'hashbangs' for the URL - so the URL would be something along the lines of `http://127.0.0.1:58164/index.html#/g. If this isn't acceptable for you, I'd look into [HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

All that being said, I don't think ngRoute will help you accomplish what you're trying to do. The router is designed to route through the pages of your app, not to external sites, so trying to load HTML from another domain probably won't work.

I'd recommend running through the [official Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) if you haven't already - it covers all this stuff quite well. I'd also recommend [Shaping Up With Angular.js on Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js), if you would prefer something a bit more hands-on.

Comment: 1. Changed. Didn't help. I still see {{ blah }} and image is missing. 2. Silly me, works in chrome live preview, not in IE live preview, I wonder where is the bug. 3. I will try my own pages instead of outside links but if I write "/g" in the when, what is the expected url that will redirect to where I want? I tried codeacademy and wanted to start something small without guidance (and failed) so I will try code school as well. Thanks

Comment: It seems that Bracket's live preview ignores all my angular js coding

Comment: Ah, I just tried your code in a jsFiddle and it's throwing this error - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=app. I think the issue is that Angular is trying to start the app before your script is loaded. Two suggestions: 1) Move your script tags to the bottom of the body - this will ensure they get loaded after the rest of the page, and is generally a good practice for page load performance anyway. 2) If that doesn't help, try getting rid of the `ngApp` directive from your `body` and add `angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["app"]);` to the end of your script.

Comment: And in answer to your other question, the URL for `when: "/g"` will be `http://127.0.0.1:58164/index.html/#/g` in your case. HTML5 mode allows you to remove the `/#/`, but requires more setup on the server-side.

Comment: I tried my code now in jsFiddle and got no error (and it doesn't work). Where do you see the error? I tried both of your solutions, none worked :( the /g /y doesn't do anything but it's maybe because of the general problem with ignoring the js

Comment: The reason it's failing now is because you're still trying to include and use ngRoute without actually having ngRoute loaded - you need to add it in a script tag after Angular, but before your app. The link to a CDN version is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js.

Comment: I still think there might be some issues with your routes though - the HTML you specify in `templateUrl` gets loaded INTO index.html, inside the ng-view div, so specifying index.html itself for the `/` doesn't really make sense. You'd need a separate template (something like `home.html`).

Comment: 1. While in jsFiddle I see blah blah and the image (buttons are active but don't do anything as expected), in live preview (chrome and IE) I see blah blah but the image is not loaded and the buttons are not responding and the page seems to be stuck. 2. so for / i redirect to "home.html" that will do what? redirect to index.html? or in my case, there is no need to redirect for "/"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102906/discussion-between-joe-clay-and-amos).